# Why Does this Example of Matrix Multiplication Work?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm fairly new to matrix multiplication and came across an example which looks wrong and I'm wondering if anyone can clarify. 
[image]
Which is said to become the following equation:
[image]

**But if with matrices you multiply row by column, and then sum, why are the two examples equivalent?**

Shouldn't the equation evaluate to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    W_{1,1}*x_1 + W_{1,2}*x_1 + W_{1,3} +x_1 \\
    W_{2,1}*x_2 + W_{2,2}*x_2 + W_{2,3} +x_2 \\
    W_{3,1}*x_3 + W_{3,2}*x_3 + W_{3,3} +x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and not

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    W_{1,1}*x_1 + W_{1,2}*x_2 + W_{1,3} +x_3 \\
    W_{2,1}*x_1 + W_{2,2}*x_2 + W_{2,3} +x_3 \\
    W_{3,1}*x_1 + W_{3,2}*x_2 + W_{3,3} +x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

as it does

**What would the correct equation be?**

Comment: Is $W_{ij}=W_{ji}  \ \forall \ i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$ ?

Comment: The first equation looks incorrect to me. It should have $x_1,x_2,x_3$ along the rows, not down the columns. Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: I literally copied the images from here: http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.md#implementing_the_regression. You'll have to scroll down.

Comment: The two equations in the picture you posted are not equivalent. The top one is probably a typo.

Comment: That's what I thought. How do I mark this question as answered if you answered it in a comment?

Comment: I made my comment an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two equations in the picture you posted are not equivalent. The top one is probably a typo.

Answer (score -4):

It looks OK to me.

To do the matrix product,
I would go
across the Ws
and down the Xs.
That gets the
WX sums.

Then the Bs are added.